# how to display the row from database with check box using php

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<?php
$usn=$_GET['usn'];
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','library');

$sql="select count(*) from book_fine where usn='$usn'";

$res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
if($row[0]>0)
{

    $sql="select * from book_fine where usn='$usn'";

    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo '<html><form><table class="table table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="check_all" id="check_all" value=""/></th>
            <th>USN</th>
            <th>Trans No</th>
            <th>Acc No</th>
            <th>category</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th>issue_date</th>
            <th>due_date</th>
            <th>renewed</th>
            <th>fine</th>
          </tr>
         ';

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

    ?>



            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="selected_id[]" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $usn; ?>"/></td>
            <?php   echo"   <td>".$row[0]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[1]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[2]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[3]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[4]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[5]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[6]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[7]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[8]."</td>
                </tr></form></html>";

    }
    echo  "</table>";



}else{
    echo "string";
}
```

?>

Comment: What result do you get when you run it? Also your printing your closing `</form></html>` within your while loop rather than after it.

Comment: Can you share a precise question? What do you expect?

Comment: code is running fine but unable to shows the check box

Comment: just i wanted to delete the row which as checked